# Why use testng.xml file to run Selenium code?

Tags: xml, selenium, testng

I have seen many time the execution of selenium code via a `testng.xml` file but I am unable to understand why we need to do this?

Comment: If you've seen it many times, it should be easy to show an example. If you can't because they're confidential, you're probably better off asking a person who wrote them, not us.

Comment: How do you execute selenium tests?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use testng.xml to run the selenium code. You can directly run your selenium code.

Your question: Why use testng.xml

my answer: In order to create a test suite and run seperate test cases, you need some framework which drive the automation. Here testng.xml can be called as "driver" which drives several test cases automated using selenium code. Hope the answers your question.

Have a nice day,
Sandeep